# What happens if you exclude a version of IE in the conditional comments?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Sorry, I'm sure this is an easy test but I don't have access to IE right now and I'm putting in some conditionals. I know it would be an easy test if I did have IE in front of me.

Let's say you have

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<body>
<p>Some content</p>
</body>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|!(IE)]><!-->
<body>
<p>Some Different content</p>
</body>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

This would exclude IE8 and so in theory/practice it would display nothing, correct? Again, sorry I don't have IE in front but I need to know before I can get a chance to get to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Versions older than IE8 will show "some content"
- Versions greater than IE8 will show "Some different content"
- Version 8 of IE will show nothing.

You should use either `gte` or `lte` to include IE8 in one of those conditionals. Further, keep in mind that Internet Explorer 10 (soon to be released) will no longer respect Conditional Comments. As such, you'll need to explicitly push your document into IE9 (or lower) mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <!-- rest of document -->
```

This way, the browser continues to interpret your conditional comments on into the future.

Further Reading: [About Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) » [Syntax of Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#syntax)

Comment: I think it's about time people gave up supporting older versions of IE.  If we all do it, it'll force people to upgrade.

Comment: @Rocket I'm afraid it's not that easy. You have corporations who rely on IE6 or 8 for internal apps. You have others who are on Windows XP and cannot install IE8+. You have yet even more who don't know how to upgrade (Microsoft is taking care of that with Automatic Updates... assuming those individuals have AU turned on), and then even more on bootleg versions of Windows who can't upgrade because their version isn't genuine.

Comment: And then you have people whose bosses still use XP and so everything you make is exclusively viewed in IE6. So they think you suck at making websites if you don't support IE6.

Comment: @Rocket: The only upgrade IE users can do are the mandatory ones included in Windows service pack updates. There's no way other than that for people to upgrade IE.

Comment: @JS. Thanks for that. Are you saying that since IE10 will not respect comments it will show both "some content" and "Some different content"?

Comment: @RKS IE10 will not render content within conditional comments, unless of course you tell it to behave as an older version of IE as I have done with the `x-ua-compatible` meta tag above. I would avoid doing that though.

Comment: Ok. I get what you're saying now. I was confused a little but you mean you can't use "if IE10" do this "endif" etc. It will ignore that unless you tell it to act like IE9. Got it. That throws a wrench in some things...